# ImGui has no member RenderPlatformWindowsDefault error

Tags: c++, imgui

When i try to build my old code i dont remember what version is imgui but i'm getting this error. i searched whole internet but i can't find nothing.

```
ImGui::GetIO().ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;
if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            ImGui::UpdatePlatformWindows();
            ImGui::RenderPlatformWindowsDefault();
        }
```

Visual studio errors:

```
Error (active) E0020 identifier "ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable" is undefined

Error (active) E0135 namespace "ImGui" has no member "UpdatePlatformWindows"

Error (active) E0135 namespace "ImGui" has no member "RenderPlatformWindowsDefault"
```

Imgui version : v1.88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code uses the [docking branch of imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/docking), and you're probably using the master branch.

You could either switch to the docking branch, or remove those lines of code if you don't need it.